# Inconsistent behaviour with nested SVG's and gradients

Tags: svg

I'm trying to use gradients in an application I'm working on, but I've run into a problem.  I'm specifically using `userSpaceOnUse`, because I want it to be applied across my SVG evenly. However, when I nest an SVG, the gradient is no longer evenly applied.  If you check the snippet I've added, you can see this in action.

I've played around, and think this might be something to do with the viewBox, but I haven't been able to fix it.

Is it possible to fix this?  Using the example I've added, I'd expect the nested SVG to perfectly match the rect behind it.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
<defs>
    <linearGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="gradient" x1="0%" x2="0%" y1="100%" y2="0%">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#FCAF45"></stop>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#833AB4"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
</defs>

<g fill="url(#gradient)">
    <rect height="100%" width="100%" x="0" y="0"></rect>
    <svg x="20" y="20" width="10" height="10"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <rect height="24" width="24" x="0" y="0"></rect>
    </svg>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Remove the inner rect element.

Comment: @RobertLongson This is missing the point, which is "I want it (the gradient) to be applied across my SVG evenly".  In the example it's not.  It's being applied to the nested element as if that element is in the top left corner.

Comment: then you'll need to remove the inner viewBox as that changes the co-ordinate system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userSpaceOnUse` is defined as

> the coordinate system that results from taking the current user coordinate system in place **at the time when the gradient element is referenced**

That means it is the local coordinate system the `<rect>` is drawn in. It does not make a difference that the gradient is *lexically* defined for the enclosing `<g>` element - CSS inheritance means it is referenced only *after* being inherited by the `<rect>`.

As a consequence, the coordinate system for the `<rect>` inside the nested `<svg>` must be the same as for any other element it is applied to. `<svg>` elements always establish their own viewport, and you only are able to make their coordinate system match when its [equivalent transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#ComputingAViewportsTransform) is the identity matrix.

In practical terms, that can be achieved when

- there is no `viewBox` attribute **and** the `x` and `y` attributes both have the value 0
- or all the values of the `viewBox` attribute are equal to the `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` attribute values.

However you do it, you have to write the child elements of the nested `<svg>` as if they were children of the outer one - you could just leave it out as well, it would make no difference.¹ Especially the geometry attributes of the `<rect>` have to be changed.

Also note that percentage values are in relation to the local viewport size. For the nested `<svg>`, this is their `width` and `height`, which differs from the root `<svg>`. Therefore you must use (implicit or explicit) `px` units for the gradient size.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
<defs>
    <linearGradient gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="gradient" x1="0" x2="0" y1="50" y2="0">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#FCAF45"></stop>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#833AB4"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
</defs>

<g fill="url(#gradient)">
    <rect height="100%" width="100%" x="0" y="0"></rect>
    <svg x="20" y="20" width="10" height="10" viewBox="20 20 10 10">
        <rect x="20" y="20" height="10" width="10"></rect>
    </svg>
</g>
</svg>
```

¹ Well, *almost*. There is a clip path applied at the viewport borders.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation!  I was able to mirror what you've done in the second bullet point successfully for simpler elements, but I'm running into viewport clipping that you've mentioned when I try to render <paths>.  I'm just wondering if you have any advice for working around this as well.  I unfortunately don't render the nested SVG's I import, so rendering the paths with the right coordinates isn't possible for me.  Thanks, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: If you don't want the clipping, would it be possible to insert the paths directly into the root svg, without the nested `<svg>`? As for path coordinates, there might be libraries available to recompute them. I have [written one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pathfit) myself for nodejs or browser environments.

Comment: This looks like it will work for my use case!

Comment: Just to update in case anybody else needs to do this:  I realized that I could attack this from the other direction by duplicating the gradient and modifying the x1,x2,y1,y2 values.  Your other post here describes how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55131536/is-it-possible-to-start-stop-svg-gradients-at-a-certain-absolute-position.  Thanks again!

Comment: It should be beneficial then to use gradient [templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/pservers.html#PaintServerTemplates) for shorter notation. Define one gradient with child `<stop>` elements, and reference it with `href` from other gradient definitions that hold the geometry attributes, but have no children.